# Doctrine - getOriginalEntityData on OnFlush

Tags: symfony, doctrine, updates, event-listener, flush

I want to keep a previous version of data entity in DDB. I create a listener on "OnFlush" to get the old data of the entity and persist another entity ("data history" entity), but I don't know how to find the old data (only in "entityChangeSets")

I tried to make it on "preUpdate" but I see on the web it is not a good idea to try to persist a new entity at this step. So I moved it on "OnFlush", but in this step, I can't get the old data of the entity

I tried to clone and refresh, `doctrine->find(id)`, `getUnitOfWork->getOriginalEntityData(entity)`... but I only got the new data of it

When and how can I get all old data of the entity, set a new entity and persist the new entity?

OR can I rollback changeSets => `rollbackChangeset(entity, getChangsets)`? Or something else?

```php
//Service listener

public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {

        foreach ($this->uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            $history = new History();

            $history->setEntityID = $entity->getID();
            $history->setEntityValue = json_encore($this->uow->getOriginalEntityData($entity));

            $this->em->persit($history);
            $metaData = $this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata(get_class($history));
            $this->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($metaData, $history);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the entity changeset. Here is an example below:

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $uow = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        $entityChangeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
    }
}
```

The `$entityChangeSet` will give you an array containing more arrays. The array key will be the property that has changed. Inside that array will be the before an after, so you'll see something like this:

```
[
    'foobar' => [
        0 => 'my old data',
        1 => 'my new data'
    ],
]
```

Maybe this will give you what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, i see that attribut. But $EM or $UOW have not a function for reset automatically the old value in Entity ? 

if there is no function, I created it myself. But I'm saving time